# Future call inside schedule batch

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, future, design-patterns

I am working on case where a scheduled batch calling a future method/class. As salesforce restricts the future call from batch , i am looking for any other alternative or workaround for this .

I need to use the future call  in schedule batch because , the dml operation i do in future call is on configuration object, performing dml operation on configuration objects causes us Mixed DML exception . To over come this error we need to use the future call.

Any light on this is of great help.

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/57393/2602

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce has pretty much deprecated the Future type of async apex. Their suggested approach is [`Queueable`s](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/10/new-apex-queueable-interface.html). Queueables allows to be executed from a batch.