# Salesforce Queueable Interface Chaining LIMIT Error

Tags: apex, queueable-interface

I'm trying to chain queueable interfaces within apex class, but receiving this error when it gets executed:

> Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2

Here's a summary of the code:

```
public without sharing class UserProcess implements Queueable{

    public UserProcess () {

    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {

        //Do stuff here
        //Chain Another Queueable Interface
        System.enqueueJob(new RankPermissionProcess(userRank));
     }

}
```

Comment: Sean, can you provide some information about how this class gets invoked.

Comment: Hi I'm calling the First Queueable Interface from a Trigger using

`Id userUpdateJobId = System.enqueueJob(new UserProcess());`

Comment: Your issue can be connected with undocumented limit for invocation of `System.enqueueJob` from batch context. See the comment here - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57367/can-queueable-solve-future-method-cannot-be-called-from-a-future-or-batch-metho/98883#98883

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you are calling the first queable from a trigger and the limit shows

> Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 1 out of 1

I believe what is happening is

- You save a record and the trigger runs.
- It enqueues your first job.
- The first job runs.
- The **//do stuff** (At line 1 in code below) performs a DML or a workflow update is triggered which causes the same trigger to fire again.
- This trigger again enqueues a job.
- Now the execution returns to line 3 which again tries to enqueue and fails.

> ```
> public without sharing class UserProcess implements Queueable{
>     public UserProcess () {
>     }
>     public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
>         1 //Do stuff here
>         2 //Chain Another Queueable Interface
>         3 System.enqueueJob(new RankPermissionProcess(userRank));
>      }
> }
> ```

Quoted from Release notes: [Queueable](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_apex_queueing_jobs.htm)

> **Queueable Apex Limits**
>
> The execution of a queued job counts once against the shared limit for
> asynchronous Apex method executions.
>
> You can add up to 50 jobs to the queue with System.enqueueJob in a single  transaction.
>
> The maximum stack depth for chained jobs is two, which means that you can link  a job only once and have a maximum of two jobs in the chain.
>
> **When chaining jobs, you can add only one job from an executing job with System.enqueueJob.**

You can use the Limits.getQueueableJobs() to check whether a job is already added.

Also you can debug a line before enqueuing job in a trigger and check how many times debug line appeared in the Log

Comment: This is right!  Seems that the Trigger is executing twice and queueing the same class in the a single transaction.

I had to check the Limits.getQueueableJobs() before I schedule the queueable class again.

`If( Limits.getQueueableJobs() == 0) {
     System.enqueueJob(new RankPermissionProcess(userRank));
}`

Answer (score 4):

I tried the below example and it works fine:

**QueueableExampleOne**

```
public class QueueableExampleOne implements Queueable{

    public void execute(QueueableContext context){
        System.debug(System.LoggingLevel.ERROR,'From queueable example one');
        System.enqueueJob(new QueuableExampleTwo());
    }

}
```

**QueuableExampleTwo**

```
public class QueuableExampleTwo implements Queueable{

    public void execute(QueueableContext ctxt){
        System.debug(System.LoggingLevel.ERROR,'From QueueableContext example two');
    }

}
```

I started the QueuebleExampleOne Job from developer console using the below code:

```
System.enqueueJob(new QueueableExampleOne());
```

And it worked fine and both the Queueable jobs execute methods executed successfully.

I am sure you might have read the below points from the documentation but posting here for the sake of complete answer.

> - No limit is enforced on the depth of chained jobs, which means that    you can chain one job to another job and repeat this process with
>     each new child job to link it to a new child job. For Developer
>     Edition and Trial organizations, the maximum stack depth for chained
>     jobs is 5, which means that you can chain jobs four times and the
>     maximum number of jobs in the chain is 5, including the initial
>     parent queueable job.
> - When chaining jobs, you can add only one job from an executing job    with System.enqueueJob, which means that only one child job can exist 
>     for each parent queueable job. Starting multiple child jobs from the
>     same queueable job isn’t supported.

Comment: I'm checking the limits on the debug logs and it's showing this limit. I thought there is no limit on the depth of chained jobs. 

  Number of DML rows: 2 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 60000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 12000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 0
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  **Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 1 out of 1 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT**
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

Comment: Do you have any other schedule or batch jobs in the same transaction? Because mine shows : **Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 1 out of 50**

Comment: I already checked **Setup>Jobs>Apex Jobs** and there are no other BatchClass that was queued on the Jobs

Comment: The parent job can enqueue up to 50 jobs per transaction, but a child's job can enqueue only one job till the dept of 5.