# Can Database.executeBatch be called from a Queueable started by System.enqueueJob?

Tags: apex, batch, asynchronous, queueable-apex

I'm aware that you can't call `Database.executeBatch` from the `execute` method of an already running `Batchable`.

But can `Database.executeBatch` be called from a `Queueable` running via `System.enqueueJob`? I'm asking because I'm looking to but an asynchronous layer on top of some code that is already using batchables.

(This [Can Queueable solve "Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method"?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57367/can-queueable-solve-future-method-cannot-be-called-from-a-future-or-batch-metho) confirms this works the opposite way round i.e. a `Queueable` can be called from a `Batchable`.)

**PS**

Interestingly, while `Batchable` -> `Batchable` isn't supported, `Batchable` -> `Queueable` -> `Batchable` is, so the `Queueable` insulates the pair of `Batchable`s from that restriction.

Comment: Yes, you can I had tried that in the anonymous window.

Comment: Cool rahul, was just about to try it. Do post as an answer, especially if you can include the code

Comment: Sure, I need to find/write that again :P give me some time I will post.

Comment: I have added the answer below, thanks!

Comment: Cool thanks. I got the same results (both ways round) too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

This is my batch class

```
public class BatchableDemo implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator('Select id from Account');
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> records){
        // process each batch of records
        system.debug('In batch');
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        // execute any post-processing operations
    }
    
}
```

This is the queueable class.

```
public class QueueableDemo implements Queueable {
    public static void execute(QueueableContext qc){
        Database.executeBatch(new BatchableDemo());
        System.debug('batch started');
    }
}
```

This is the code I ran from the anonymous window.

```
System.enqueueJob(new QueueableDemo());
```

### Output

**Queueable job log**

[image]

**Batch Job log**

[image]

**All logs list**

[image]